# A Bootstrap Card in Pricing Table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am taking the lesson in bootstrap card, and I have followed the whole story from my teacher, but the grid markup effect could not work.

I thought I was incorrect for what I have input, but I realized I wasn't.

I suppose to create the first two containers with 50% in the PAD and the 3rd container with 100%.

I added    in the first 2 container and      for the 3rd.

What I inputted is entirely the same from the lesson, but it could not work nicely as a pricing table.

Please kindly advice what I suppose to do.

Please kindly to see what I have input below in my codeply
https://www.codeply.com/p/uA7F2o9gyz

[image: The right effect- it suppose like this]

[image: The one I learnt from my teacher but different effected.]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">

  <!-- css stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <!-- fontawesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e2fafd992e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Script -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>


<!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card-body">
        <h2>Free</h2>
        <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
        <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Labrador</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Mastiff</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
          <p>Pirority Listing</p>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: card-header and card-body divs should be nested inside card div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first card body div is outside the card div that's why you are facing this problem.

```
  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
        <h2>Free</h2>
        <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
        <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
        <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
        <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

      </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Labrador</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Mastiff</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
          <p>Pirority Listing</p>
          <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
          <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
          <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
          <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `.card-body` is outside of the first card.  It should be inside the card `div`, after the `.card-header` `div` like the others.  The card structure should look like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
   //card header content here
  </div> //close card-header div
  <div class="card-body">
   //card body content here
  </div> //close card-body div
</div> //close card div
```

Just cut-and-paste the entire `.card-body` block right after `<h3>Chihuahua</h3></div>`